# How to get babel to work with new threejs versions

Tags: ios, webview, babeljs

I am having trouble updating threejs to the new es6 class version that they introduced because I am having trouble with babel.

I have the following code where I am extending Object3D

```
import {
  Object3D,
} from "three";

type Props = {
  myProp:string
};

export default class MyBox extends Object3D {
  constructor(props: Props = {}) {
    super();
    console.log("HERE");
    this.init(props);
    console.log("Done");
  }
  init(props){
    // Do stuff
   }
```

Now this works in almost every case just fine, except when I am trying to load it in an ios webview. In that case I drilled down and saw that my code is transpiled to

```
function e() {
            var e,
                o = arguments.length > 0 && void 0 !== arguments[0] ? arguments[0] : {};
            return e = n.call(this) || this, console.log("HERE"), e.init(o), console.log("DOne"), e
```

Which on the ios webview throws an error saying:

TypeError: Cannot call a class constructor without |new|

Which to me means since Object3D is a class it cannot be called like the transpiled version wants to.

```
{
  
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-flow", ["@babel/preset-env",
    {
      "targets": ">1%"
  }], "@babel/react"],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/transform-runtime",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-flow",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
}
```

I have tried playing with the targets property and other packages, but have had no luck. My understanding is the threejs is not getting transpiled, whereas the rest of my code is.

Edit: I was wrong about the cause, it was actually due to Meteor build systems misdetecting whether this was a legacy case or not

Comment: You might want to add ios or webview tags to your question for better visibility. This doesn't really look like a Three.js issue.

Comment: Yeah I believe this is much more of a babel question than threejs, since it is babel that is doing the weird thing. Threejs made its choice to move away from es5 classes which is the cause of my headache.

I have found a way to transpile the threejs so I can get it to work, but it ends up breaking my build and circleci because transpiling threejs is taking too much memory.

Comment: So I ended up figuring this was due to our build system (meteor) forcing this specific case to believe it was a legacy browser that this needed to happen on, when it wasn't. I needed to force tell the build system to mark webviews as modern and I was fine

Answer (score 0):

Answer for me ended up being:

```
import { setMinimumBrowserVersions } from "meteor/modern-browsers";
setMinimumBrowserVersions(
    {
      "mobileSafariUI/WKWebView": 10,
    },
    "classes"
  );
```